# Entering wrong captcha and clicking on submit button clearing all the form field values in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i have request form if i enter wrong captcha and click on submit button all the form fields which i have entered are getting cleared.If there is any error in the captcha form only the captcha has to be refreshed and the form values should not be cleared.

View:

```
<form name="contact"  id="contactform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/request">
<div class="name"><span class="mandatory"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo set_value('name');?>"  required>
    <?php echo form_error('name', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
</div>
<div class="name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo set_value('phone');?>" placeholder="Phone" MinLength ="10" MaxLength="10" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required>
    <?php echo form_error('phone', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
</div>
<div class="email">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required value="<?php echo set_value('email');?>"/>
    <?php echo form_error('email', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
</div>
<div class="description">
    <textarea name="description"  style="width:100%;overflow:auto;" id="description" placeholder="Description" maxlength="3000" required value="<?php echo set_value('description');?>"/></textarea>
</div>
<p class="entertext">Enter Image Text</p>
<div class="">
    <div class="captchas">
        <div class="captchatexts" ><?php echo $captchaImg;?></div>
        <p id = 'ref_symbol' class='refresh clickto'>Click to change</p>
    </div>
    <div class="captcha">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="captcha" name="captcha"  style="background-color: #EAD5D2;border: none;" required>
        <?php echo form_error('captcha', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>   
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" value="true" name="isSubmitted">
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="return validate();"  >Submit</button><!--  id="demo"!-->

</form>
```

Controller:

```
function request()
{
        $this->load->library('form_validation');


         if ($this->input->post('email')) 
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error"> ','</span>');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','First Name' , 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone','Mobile Number','required|numeric');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'required');

            if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)   
            {   
                /*echo "valid";
                print_r($this->input->post());
                exit;*/
                $data['mainpage']='index';
                $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
            }       
            else
            {
                /*echo "invalid";
                print_r($this->input->post());
                exit;*/
                $inputCaptcha = $this->input->post('captcha');
                $sessCaptcha  = $this->session->userdata('captchaCode');

                if ($inputCaptcha === $sessCaptcha)
                {
                    $result = $this->index_model->send_mail($this->input->post('email'));

                    if ($result)
                    {
                        $this->flash->success('<h2 style="color:green">Thank You! Your  Message has been sent</h2>');
                        redirect('welcome');
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $this->flash->success('<h2 style="color:red">Sorry ! Message sending failed</h2>');
                        redirect('welcome');
                    }
                } 
                else
                {
                   $this->flash->success('<h2 style="color:red;font-size:15px;margin-top:6px;">Please enter correct captcha.</h2>');
                    redirect('welcome');                    
                }
            }
        }

     $config  = array(
        'img_path' => 'captcha_images/',
        'img_url' => base_url() . 'captcha_images/',
        'img_width' => '125',
        'img_height' => 35,
        'word_length' => 6,
        'font_size' => 30
    );
    $captcha = create_captcha($config);
    $word    = $captcha['word'];
    $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
    $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode', $word);        
    $data['captchaImg'] = $captcha['image'];
    //$data['captchaImg'] = $captcha['image'];
    $data['mainpage']   = "index";
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

Can anyone please help me out this

Comment: Any solution for this can anyone sort my problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't load view twice, try to remove the loading of view from `if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)` because when the view loads then `set_value` inside it is triggered and you have called loading view after creating captcha. So remove the load view when validation errors are there like,

```
....
if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)  {   
  /*echo "valid";
  print_r($this->input->post());
  exit;*/
  $data['mainpage']='index';
  // comment the below line, otherwise there are no loophole in your code
  //$this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
....
```

Hope the above will work for you.

Comment: Actually it is not a page there are 4 blocks in my website which is divided by col-md-3 and one of the block is the one which i posted

Comment: But i am using CI2 version